# How to equalize in-game sensitivity between two FPS games

Tags: mouse, first-person-shooter

After playing a F2P FPS game I've decided to train my aim and recently found a guide which shows how to train your aim in CS:GO using harmless bots.

After I tried a bit, I realized that I would need the same **in-game** mouse sensitivity between two games because first game had real-time weapon module system which had different scopes with different magnification levels which means different force applied to the mouse in order to line up a shot and reduce recoil.

But everything I could find was a guide which barely explains how to make your in-game sensitivity the same as the desktop one.

So how do you do It?(If you do It)Do i need macro in order to achieve this? Is this the right method to improve my aim?

Comment: There's no way to do this; each game uses different settings and values to denote the same thing.  It's also very subjective, as each player will require different settings for different games.

Comment: But first thing I thought was : record a macro for 360 degree turn in one game and then adjust the sensitivity in the other game until the turn will be 360 degree.I don't care about my sensitivity in cs:go i am going to use it as a practice game.I don't play it at all!

Comment: Then you should be using the game you're actually going to play as training; it will be much more helpful than playing a completely different game.

Comment: Well but it would require MUCH more time because the game is 8x8 session shooter and it doesn't have a mode with harmless bots.Plus the time until everyone will press "ready" button.

Comment: Playing the actual game will give you much more benefit than just getting used to the mouse sensitivity.  It will teach you the maps, strategies, where to aim, and many other important things.  The amount of utility you will get from playing a completely different game will be strictly limited.

Comment: @ohemgee I think your 360 degree macro idea is probably the best place to start.  I think you'd need to use some software that can do this outside of both games.  It might be helpful to edit in the name of the F2P FPS game into the question, though I think this question isn't bounded by either of the games you're using.

Comment: Maps are as small as de_dust2x2(even smaller) and I know them.But because game is actually P2W just knowledge of maps and tactics isn't enough to win at least 75% of matches.

Comment: @tugs the game is Warface. Currently I play on RU servers.

Comment: @ohemgee I edited the tags on your question a bit. It looks like you're looking for a solution that you can use across *all* FPS games, not just CSGO and Warface. Due to this the [tag:first-person-shooter] tag is more apprioate than the individual game tags. If you're really just looking for a solution for the specific games you're playing then feel free to roll back my edit.

Answer (score 8):

Mouse movement interpretation can be vastly different between different game-engines, and often even between different games using the same engine. There is no standard for mouse sensitivity, so the only way to measure it is to use our own impression.

When I start a new FPS game, the first thing I do to calibrate the mouse sensitivity is:

1. close my eyes
2. Perform what I feel is a 90° turn
3. open my eyes and see how far my character actually turned
4. adjust mouse sensitivity accordingly
5. repeat until a "felt" 90° turn is an "actual" 90° turn.

Instead of a 90° turn you can also perform a flick-movement between two points.

1. Take two points in the game worlds you can see on the same screen (like two sides of a door frame, or two edges of a crate)
2. place your crosshair over one of them
3. perform a fast mouse movement, which should place your crosshair exactly on the other one
4. see how far you overshot or undershot and adjust sensitivity accordingly.

I could also imagine a third, more exact but more technical method.

1. Place your mouse on a piece of paper
2. start game A
3. mark the position of your mouse on the paper by drawing a line at its edge
4. perform an exact 90° turn
5. mark the new position of your mouse and measure the distance with a ruler. You now have the exact distance you move your mouse to perform a 90° turn
6. load game B and repeat steps 3-5
7. adjust mouse sensitivity until the distances of a 90° turn in game A and game B are the same

Games use different FOV (field of view) angles. Maybe you feel better with calibrating your mouse sensitivity for the FOV and not for the game world. In that case replace the 90° turn with aiming at a point and moving your mouse until the point you aimed at is exactly at the border of your screen.

Comment: Can't I do the same thing with macro which is loaded into on-board mouse memory not simulated by software driver?

Comment: @ohemgee I doubt that your mouse even has on-board memory.

Comment: Well it's bloody v7 and I also have a4tech x7-747h mouse.And I am sure that they have on-board memory!

Comment: @ohemgee When you have questions about how to use the macro manager of your mouse, you might be more successful on superuser.com or on the forum of the manufacturer.

Comment: Very nice guide, it will help me a lot in the future!

Comment: @Philipp Believe me I have experience in writing macro.I just want to know is that method right or not.

Comment: @ohemgee "And I am sure that they have on-board memory!" A mouse is an input device - it rarely has any reason to care about feedback, let alone memory.  Unless the specs for your mouse specifically state it has on-board memory (which it might - but only on a high-end gaming mouse), it doesn't have on-board memory.  You might be able to find tools that will record your mouse motion, but those would be separate from your mouse.

Answer (score 3):

All games use completely different interpretations of the sensitivity slider (if there even is a sensitivity slider). Battlefield 3 even, much to my annoyance, makes extreme differences in sensitivity between vehicle aiming and on-foot aiming.

You'll simply have to fuss with both (or more) games to try and get the sensitivities close enough. Easiest way to do this is play both games in windowed mode and attempt to move the same mouse the same distance in both games until they're close to matching. I recommend disabling mouse acceleration (in windows, and sometimes in games separately) to keep movements consistent as well (otherwise you might move your mouse quickly in panic and overshoot, or delicately aim a shot and find yourself not moving quite far enough before the dreaded edge of the mousepad).

However, aiming in any two FPS games requires lots of the same physical skill and muscle memory. As long as there's a 1:1 correlation between mouse and cursor movement with no acceleration or deceleration, you can train the act of aiming fairly well in any game. The main differences between games will be exactly how fast the weapon fires, how fast the projectiles hit, how close you need to be, etc. So training with a hitscan weapon in Call of Duty is not going to help your aim in a game with somewhat slow projectiles like Borderlands 2. The best you can do is train in *the same game* or at least something very similar in terms of game speed, player movement speed, projectile speed.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there are drivers and dll files that will ignore ingame mouse sensitivity and only base it on your windows sensitivity. Thus it will keep the same mouse sens for ALL games since your mouse will be moving at a universal speed according to your windows sensitivity. I don't remember the program off the top of my head because I quit FPS some 5 years ago, but I'm sure you can find it in Google.

Programs might be detected as cheating from your game engine, but mouse drivers and dlls won't (given that you are using a mouse speed dll and not a hack). I recall I had the same problem you used to have, playing between CS 1.6, CS Source, and Osu, but that was eventually all fixed by one mouse driver :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one , an application to make your sensitivity constant betweens FPS games,the link is here, http://www.mouse-sensitivity.com/

Answer (score 0):

Jeff has an excellent answer here with the reference to mouse-sensitivity.com, but let me explain the method behind that site so you have the alternative of doing it the old fashioned way.

Get a ruler or tape measure and put it in front of your mouse, horizontally across your mouse pad. Open a game that you already has your sensitivity set to what you feel is comfortable, and what you want to duplicate in other games. Open that game up and spawn into any map where you won't be harassed for a few seconds.

*Make sure mouse acceleration is turned off.* If you're using mouse acceleration, just don't. It's killing your ability to aim. If you're using a Mac, which has acceleration locked to on, then I weep for you. You'll need to find a utility to turn it off.

Now, face a distinctive point in the map; something easy to recognize and get a fine aim on. Texture details that form right angles are good for this.

Put your mouse on the left side of your mouse pad with the left side of your mouse lined up with the zero on the ruler.

Turn to the right until you've spun 360-degrees and are pointing precisely at the spot you were before the turn. Note on the length on the ruler.

Repeat this process in a second game, adjusting your sensitivity until you match the same distance as in the prior game.

Average competitive 360-turn distances are between 15-50cm, with 15cm being considered high sensitivity and 50 (yes, that's half a meter!) as very low. I tend to run in the 20cm range myself.

Comment: As of Mac OS X 10.10, mouse acceleration is turned off by default.

Answer (score 0):

I use this method:

It's for Overwatch but can be applied to all fps games I guess

Comment: Please edit your answer to incorporate the relevant parts of the video in case the video link dies in the future.